# How to take faster screenshots using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use this command to take screenshots from a video:

```
 ffmpeg  -i input.mkv -r 0.0033 -vf scale=-1:120 -vcodec png capture-%002d.png
```

But usually it takes several minutes even on a powerful machine. I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do so?